# Scala: Sum values across arrays based on key

Tags: scala

Very novice Scala programmer so hopefully this is pretty simple.

I have an array of tuples that looks like this:

```
Array((1,Array(1.0,0.0,5.2,0.0), 
      (1,Array(1.0,0.0,6.3,0.0),
      (2,Array(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.2),
      (2,Array(0.0,1.0,0.0,2.5))
```

I want to sum up the corresponding values in the second part of the tuple based on the key in the first.   So the result would look like this:

```
Array((1,(2.0,0.0,11.5,0.0),
      (2,(0.0,2.0,0.0,3.7))
```

The function I came up with is:

```
def sumByKeys[A](tuples: Array[(String, Array[Double])]) = {
    tuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
}
```

There error I get is

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Array[Double]]
       tuples.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
                                                  ^
```

I'm hoping this is something simple where I am just messing up the data types.

Thanks.

Comment: why didn't you just use a `Map` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> a.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).transpose.map(_.sum)).toArray
res2: Array[(Int, Array[Double])] = Array((2,Array(0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.7)),
                                          (1,Array(2.0, 0.0, 11.5, 0.0)))
```

Comment: This does it exactly.  Thanks!